# Ember.js: Complex view layout, what's the proper approach?

Tags: ember.js

We're building app that allows users to post messages to various social media outlets. Our designer has created a series of interactions which allow users to change various settings in their application by use of sliding panels. I've done a quick screen cap to illustrate:

http://screencast.com/t/tDlyMud7Yb7e

The question I have is one of architecture. I'm not sure whether I should be using a View or a Controller (or both) to store some of the methods these panels will contain. Here's the HTML for the panels. They're not currently in a script tag or view:

```
<div id="panel-account-settings" class="panel closed">
    <div class="panel-inner">
        <a href="#" class="button button-close"><i class="icon-cancel"></i>close</a>
        <h3>Account Settings</h3>
        <a href="#" class="button primary button-ga">Google Analytics</a>
        <a href="#" class="button primary button-link-shortening">Link Shortening</a>
        <a href="/accounts/social/connections/" class="button button-disconnect">Disconnect Account</a>
    </div>
    <div id="panel-google-analytics" class="panel-inner">
        <a href="#" class="button button-back"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>back</a>
        <h3>Google Analytics</h3>
        <div class="toggle">
            <label>Off</label>
        </div>
        <p>We <strong>won't</strong> append stuff to your links, so they <strong>won't</strong> be trackable in your Google Analytics account.</p>
        <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/ga-addressbar.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="panel-disconnect" class="panel-inner">
        <a href="#" class="button button-back"><i class="icon-arrow-right"></i>back</a>
        <h3>Disconnect This Account</h3>
        <p>If you disconnect this account you will lose all the metrics we tracked for each message. Are you absolute sure you want to get rid of them?</p>
        <div class="button-group">
            <a href="#" class="button button-disconnect">Disconnect</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The gear icon shown in the video is contained with the accounts template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="accounts">
    {{#each account in controller}}
        <div class="avatar-name">
            <p>{{account.name}}</p>
            <p>@{{account.username}}</p>
            <i class="icon-cog" {{action "openPanel" Social.SettingsView account }}></i>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

which has a bare bones controller

```
Social.AccountsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    openPanel: function(view,account){
        console.log(view,account);
        $(this).parents(".item-account").addClass("active");
        $("#panel-account-settings").prepareTransition().removeClass("closed");
    }
});
```

as well as a Route and a Model. Given the interaction I'm looking to accomplish, my question is where should I be putting the pieces and parts? At a minimum I need to pass in the current Account model so that I know which account I'll be applying changes to. I thought about creating a mainPanel view which would contain the other view...something like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="panelView">
    <div id="panel-account-settings" class="panel closed">
        {{ partial "panelSettingsView" }}
        {{ partial "panelAnalyticsView" }}
        {{ partial "panelDisconnectView" }}
    </div>
</script>
```

and then the action helper on the gear icon could pass in the account AND the required view. But I'm not sure if that's the right approach. I'd appreciate some input or suggestions. Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

Ideally I'd like to eventually load in the content of each panel via AJAX but that's a want to, not a need to.

**UPDATE 2**

I tried creating a PanelView which would contain the logic on which panels to load:

```
Social.PanelView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    classNames: ['panel-inner'],
    openPanel: function(view,account){
        console.log(view,account);
    }
});
```

But when I tried to call it from the gear icon I got an error. This:

```
<i class="icon-cog" {{action openPanel target="Social.PanelView" }}></i>
```

Threw this error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: The action 'openPanel' did not exist on Social.PanelView
```

Isn't that the correct syntax?

**UPDATE 3**

Adding version information:

```
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.1
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1
```

Comment: This doesn't quite answer your question, but the target of your action needs to be the instance of the view view class. Something like `{{action openPanel target="view"}}`

Comment: Mehul. The problem is that the controller for Accounts isn't related to the the Panel view. Perhaps that's part of my problem. I just don't see them as related though. I am having success doing this though: `<i class="icon-cog" {{ action "openPanel" account }}></i>`. Problem is that the openPanel method is on the controller and I think it should be on the View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to always put any DOM- or UI-related logic into your view, and leave data representation to the controller (i.e., a reference to a 'selected' item in the controller is a common example).

Your `Social.AccountsController.openPanel` method has logic that touches the DOM, which is entirely a view concern. A good start would be to move that logic into the view (`Social. SettingsView` ?).

It'd be a bit easier to understand your goals and offer more suggestions if you had a jsfiddle of what you have so far.

EDIT: Another good practice is to decompose things into very small objects. So you could explore having a `selectedAccount` ObjectController whose content is the currently chosen Account (and a corresponding View for it).

Comment: Sheldon, thanks for your input. I've added update 2 which moves the openPanel method to a View. Would you mind looking at that?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to trigger an event on a view class (instead of an instance of the instance). Try changing the target parameter in your action helper to "view".

What version of Ember are you using?

Comment: Yes, in this case the button doing the triggering lives within the account template (AccountsController). The View I want to use is PanelView. Is that not possible? I've added version information into update 3.

Comment: You shouldn't be referencing PanelView like that (since it's a class, and not an actual instance that has been created). Inside the panelView template, you should be able to set the openPanel action target to be `view` (your PanelView instance).

I'd also take an additional gander through [the routing guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/) to understand the Ember way a bit better. :)

Comment: Sheldon. First off, thanks for your time and energy...it's appreciated. The button with the action helper isn't contained within PanelView, it's contained with the account template. As I understand it if I say `target="view"` it would attempt to call `openPanel` on AccountsView, then continue bubbling to the Router. That's not how my app is currently set up. Of course that could be the problem, but it makes sense to me.

Comment: Oh, and this interaction isn't using the Router as I don't care about the URL. This is completely within the context of the `accounts` route.

Comment: No problem. I think I'd be able to offer a helpful answer if you provided a jsfiddle, but from the obviously small amount I'm understanding, it sounds like the PanelView logic is separate from the accounts logic, and so an optimal solution could be to have the action propagate up to the router, and then the router would tell the panel view to open up. Sorry for all the confusion I probably caused. :)

Comment: One last comment: [this](http://www.kaspertidemann.com/calling-a-controller-action-from-a-view-via-the-needs-api-in-ember-js/) blog post might be useful.

Comment: I'll work on a fiddle tomorrow. It might actually help me clear my head around this.